# Two Boolean states in the Init State of Reducer, One returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been working with redux for the last couple weeks and was incorporating it into my projects when I ran into this wall. Pretty common reducer for modals being rendered so i can animate them before unmounting them.

```
const initialState = {
  isModalOpen: false,
  test: false
}
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "modalInteraction":
      return {
        isModalOpen: action.payload
      };
    case "testModalInteraction":
      return {
        test: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  };
}
```

Sadly, the test property is still returning as undefined despite the fact that the other initial state in the same reducer can be called without a problem. I even removed all the testModalInteraction dispatches in the case that that somehow upset the datatype. I just can't spot the difference that keeps returning undefined.

Comment: In each branch you are excluding the other property. This can be resolved with very common immutable patterns. Can you try `return { ...state, isModalOpen: action.payload }` for the modal interaction branch?

Comment: I have and it still returns as undefined.

Comment: You need to use spread basically in each branch other than default to ensure you don’t erase properties.

Answer (score 0):

When you return the new state, make sure to spread the initial state (`...state`) and then change whatever values you need to change.

```
const initialState = {
  isModalOpen: false,
  test: false
}
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "modalInteraction":
      return {
        ...state,
        isModalOpen: action.payload
      };
    case "testModalInteraction":
      return {
        ...state,
        test: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  };
}
```

If it is still undefined, make sure the payloads are defined for both actions.
For example, your `modalInteraction` action could look like

```
export const modalInteraction = (bool) => ({
  type: "modalInteraction",
  payload: bool
})
```

P.S., you can destructure the action object. This allows you to use "type" instead of "action.type" and "payload" instead of "action.payload".

```
const initialState = {
  isModalOpen: false,
  test: false
}
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const {type, payload} = action;
  switch (type) {
    case "modalInteraction":
      return {
        ...state,
        isModalOpen: payload
      };
    case "testModalInteraction":
      return {
        ...state,
        test: payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  };
}
```